# How can I catch or stop a Linux shut down from the terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shutdown

Is there a way to catch or stop a Linux shut down after a reboot, halt or shutdown command has been entered?

```
sudo shutdown -r +10
```

I should now have 10 minutes before the computer shuts down. If I change my mind and decide that I still want to continue running, how could I stop the shut down?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sudo shutdown -c
```

This will cancel a scheduled shutdown. You *don't* have to run it in the same terminal as the original shutdown request.